# Angular routing issue unable to perform events

Tags: angularjs, routes

I am having two html files in my app folder as follows

app
| - Home.html
| - Folder - Employee.html and Employee.controller.js
| - app.module.js
| - app.route.js

My Home.html is as follows

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <link href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="/Scripts/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-ui-router/1.0.3/angular-ui-router.js"></script>
    <script src="/app/app.module.js"></script>
    <script src="/app/app.routes.js"></script>
    <script src="/app/Folder/Employee.controller.controller.js"></script>
</head>
<body ng-app="employeeModule">
    <ui-view>
        <i>Some content will load here!</i>
    </ui-view>
    <a href="/app/JobCard/JobProcessCard.html">Link</a>
</body>
</html>
```

My app.module.js is as follows

```
(function () {
    "use strict";
    angular.module('employeeModule', ['ui.router']);
})();
```

My app.route.js is as follows

```
(function () {

    'use strict';

    angular.module('employeeModule').config(employeeAppConfiguration);

    function employeeAppConfiguration($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider, $locationProvider) {
        $locationProvider.hashPrefix('');
        $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/');
        $stateProvider

            .state('home', {
                url: '',
                abstract: true,
                views: {
                    'home': {
                        templateUrl: '/app/Home.html'
                    }
                }
            })
            .state('home.employee', {
                url: '/employee',
                templateUrl: '/app/Folder/Employee.html',
                controller: 'employeeController',
                controllerAs: 'empCtrl'
            });
    }
})();
```

My controller is as follows

```
(function () {
    'use strict';
    angular.module('employeeModule')
        .controller('employeeController', employeeController);

    function employeeController() {
        var ctrl = this;
        ctrl.employee;
        ctrl.submitEmployee= submitEmployee;

        function submitEmployee(employee) {

        }
    };
});
```

I am unable to see the submitEmployee function called on my submit click this is is my html

Add

Can some one help me where I am going wrong

Answer (score 0):

probably address of youre controller is misspelled

```
   <script src="/app/Folder/Employee.controller.controller.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

incorrect controller file name. Change it to`<script src="/app/Folder/Employee.controller.js"></script>`